# List generate through pattern match

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I need to find progression length. When the sum of this progression is equal to sumVal. Let's suppose this task always has answer.

```
findN :: Integer -> Integer
findN sumVal = n where
    sum [1,2..n] = sumVal
```

Example:

```
findN 55 --evaluates to 10
```

My solution has error

> Parse error in pattern [1,2..n]

How to fix my code? Is it possible to do it such way, with pattern match? I don't want to do it recursive: iterate through the list and accumulate sum until it not equal to sumVal.

Maybe another elegant solution?

Comment: What do you expect `..n` to do inside the pattern?

Comment: This is asking for too much magic. Haskell will not try all the possible values of `n` looking for one which works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how Haskell works. Haskell is not that *declarative*. If you write something like:

```
patter = expression
```

it thus expects a pattern on the left, and an expression on the right. `sum [1,2..n]` is not a pattern: it is an expression.

Next `=` is *not* equality*: it is a *declaration*: that means that you define a pattern in terms of an expression. Since you already defined `sumVal` in the head of the function, you can not define it in the `where` clause again.

So how can we solve this? We can construct a recursive function that constructs a running sum until it reaches the requested sum `sumVal` and then returns the last number it added to it. Like:

```
findN :: Integer -> Integer
findN sumVal = go 0 0
    where go n s | s == sumVal = n
                 | otherwise = go (n+1) (s+n+1)
```

So if we want to find the `n` for a sum, we call `go 0 0` with the first `0` the last element we added to the sum, and the second `0` the thus far obtained sum. Each time we check if the running sum `s` is equal to `sumVal`. If that is the case, we return `n`, the last added element. If the sum is not equal, we perform recursion with `go (n+1) (s+n+1)`: we update the element added to `n+1`, and do this for the running sum as well.

The above solution is not very safe, nor is it generic. A first problem that arises is that we might call the function with a `sumVal` we can never obtain: for instance `findN 14`. In that case the program will keep looping forever: it will keep updating the sum, but never find an `n` for which the sum is `14`. We can solve this issue by constructing a function that returns a `Maybe Integer`: if the sum exists, we return `Just n`, otherwise we return `Nothing`.

We know the sum does not exists if the running sum is larger than the requested sum. So we can alter the code to:

```
findN :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
findN sumVal = go 0 0
    where go n s | s == sumVal = Just n
                 | s > sumVal = Nothing
                 | otherwise = go (n+1) (s+n+1)
```

We can also generalize the function to work with all numerical types `Num` that can be ordered `Ord`:

```
findN :: (Num n, Ord n) => n -> Maybe n
findN sumVal = go 0 0
    where go n s | s == sumVal = Just n
                 | s > sumVal = Nothing
                 | otherwise = go (n+1) (s+n+1)
```

It might be an idea to add `Integral n` as a type constraint as well to prevent us to work with `Double`s and `Float`s where the precisions can be a problem.

Finally the solution is not very efficient. We know that the sum of such list is:

```
 n
---
\        n * (n+1)
/    i = --------- = s
---         2
i=0
```

So that means that:

```
     ________
    V 8 s + 1 - 1
n = -------------
           2
```

So we calculate the square root of `8 * s + 1`, calculate whether that is an odd integral root, and then subtract one from it and divide it by two to obtain `n`. If the root is not integral or odd, we should return `Nothing`.

For `Integer`s, we can use the integral square root that is available on the [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Generic_number_type#squareRoot):

> ```
> (^!) :: Num a => a -> Int -> a
> (^!) x n = x^n
>
> squareRoot :: Integer -> Integer
> squareRoot 0 = 0
> squareRoot 1 = 1
> squareRoot n =
>    let twopows = iterate (^!2) 2
>        (lowerRoot, lowerN) =
>           last $ takeWhile ((n>=) . snd) $ zip (1:twopows) twopows
>        newtonStep x = div (x + div n x) 2
>        iters = iterate newtonStep (squareRoot (div n lowerN) * lowerRoot)
>        isRoot r  =  r^!2 <= n && n < (r+1)^!2
>    in  head $ dropWhile (not . isRoot) iters
> ```

Then we can use:

```
findN :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
findN 0 = Just 0
findN sumVal | r * r == sq && odd r = Just (div (r-1) 2)
             | otherwise = Nothing
    where sq = 8*sumVal+1
          r = squareRoot sq
```

This then produces:

```
*Main> findN 0
Just 0
*Main> findN 1
Just 1
*Main> findN 2
Nothing
*Main> findN 3
Just 2
*Main> findN 4
Nothing
*Main> findN 5
Nothing
*Main> findN 6
Just 3
*Main> findN 55
Just 10
```